# How to do different things according to type but not using overriding?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, overriding, generic-programming

For example, I have some Shape, and each shape return different types of buttons:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct Button{
    Button(){
        printf("Button\n");
    }
};

struct CircleButton : public Button{
    CircleButton(){
        printf("CircleButton\n");
    }
};

struct SquareButton : public Button{
    SquareButton(){
        printf("SquareButton\n");
    }
};

struct Shape{
    virtual Button* getNewButton()=0;
};

struct Circle : public Shape{
    Button* getNewButton(){
        return new CircleButton();
    }
};

struct Square : public Shape{
    Button* getNewButton(){
        return new CircleButton();
    }
};
```

by using override I can write some generic code:

```
int main(){
    Shape* s=new Circle();
    Button* b=s->getNewButton();
    return 0;
}
```

but now the shape is data transfer object, which should not have any methods:

```
struct Shape{
};

struct Circle : public Shape{
};

struct Square : public Shape{
};
```

and I want to keep my generic code, I tried:

```
struct Helper{
    static Button* getNewButton(Shape* s){
        return new Button();
    }

    static Button* getNewButton(Circle* s){
        return new CircleButton();
    }

    static Button* getNewButton(Square* s){
        return new SquareButton();
    }
};

int main(){
    Shape* s=new Circle();
    Button* b=Helper::getNewButton(s);
    return 0;
}
```

but this time I cannot get a new CircleButton, how to modify the code, or what design pattern can apply, so that I can get different type of button according to different shape, but not implementing any methods in Shape, Circle and Square?

Comment: What is the point of a class that does nothing but simply return a new instance of another class? They could be just standalone functions.

Comment: You can look into using the `Vistor Pattern`.

Comment: Why? What's your aversion to overriding virtual functions?

Comment: What's the point in using inheritance for data transfer objects which do not have methods, either virtual or not? Why does Circle inherit Shape if it does not have any behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The [Factory Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) is the most likely solution to your problem.

You could make use of RTTI to inspect the type of the button (making the destructor of Button virtual will allow you to use dynamic_cast) and allow capturing only if the button is already the proper type using the approach below:

```
struct Shape {
    // Store the allocated button
    unique_ptr<Button> ptr;

    Shape()
    {
       ptr.reset(nullptr);
    }
    Shape(Button* otherButton)
    {
       ptr.reset(otherButton); 
    }

    virtual bool containsValidButton()
    {
        return ptr != nullptr;
    }
};

struct Circle : public Shape {
    Circle(Button* otherButton)
    {
        ptr.reset(dynamic_cast<Circle*>(otherButton) ? otherButton : nullptr);
    }
};
```

This keeps a generic interface but will not store a button if the user passes in an improper button type to the constructor.

A factory method you could employ would involve creating an enum parameter (as noted in the example in the previous link) to signify to your factory method what type of Button to create:

```
enum ButtonType
{
    SQUARE,
    CIRCLE
};

static unique_ptr<Button> GetNewButton(ButtonType bType)
{
    unique_ptr<Button> ptr;
    switch (bType)
    {
    case SQUARE:
        ptr.reset(new SquareButton());
        break;
    case CIRCLE:
        ptr.reset(new CircleButton());
        break;
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

A similar approach one can use (again using RTTI) in the constructor of Square or Circle:

```
static unique_ptr<Button> GetNewButton(Shape* shape)
{
    unique_ptr<Button> ptr;
    if (dynamic_cast<Circle*>(shape))
    {
        ptr.reset(new CircleButton());
    }
    if (dynamic_cast<Square*>(shape))
    {
        ptr.reset(new SquareButton());
    }
    return ptr;
}

struct Square : public Shape {
    Square()
    {
        ptr = GetNewButton(this);
    }
};
```

See article on [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) if you're curious as to how dynamic_cast works its magic in the above case.

Note: you might have to use forward declarations (if not including declarations in a header file) for the above snippet to compile.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't allow **any methods at all** in your classes, I don't see any design solution that solves this issue. Only some sort of typing mechanism like class ID, Enum or instanceOf will allow you to figure out the type of the object you are handing in run-time. Obviously this is not recommended particularly the use of instanceOf since it violates the [DIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

But I am curious about why you prohibit any inner methods? You do realize that is the whole essence of encapsulation?

If you didn't mean any methods per say, but rather meant inner structures, then in that case the [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern is a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

`boost::variant` may help

```
using ShapeVariant = boost::variant<Circle, Square>;

class to_button : public boost::static_visitor<std::unique_ptr<Button>>
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Button> operator ()(const Circle&) const
    {
        return std::make_unique<CircleButton>();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Button> operator ()(const Square&) const
    {
        return std::make_unique<SquareButton>();
    }
};
```

And usage:

```
ShapeVariant shape = GetShape();
boost::apply_visitor(to_button(), shape);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2e657ede1a40ed5)

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much stuck with RTTI of one kind or another if you're going to go with an OOP approach. But if you really want to do "generic programming" as your tag implies, then go fully generic! Non-member function specialization can get you there, for example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
// Shapes
struct Circle { };
struct Square { };

// Buttons
struct Button {
    virtual void click() { printf("Button clicked\n"); }
};

struct CircleButton : Button {
    void click() override { printf("CircleButton clicked\n"); }
};

struct SquareButton : Button {
    void click() override { printf("SquareButton clicked\n"); }
};

// Button creation

template<typename TShape>
auto getNewButton(const TShape& shape)
{
    static_assert(false, "Don't know how to create a button for this type.");
}

template<>
auto getNewButton(const Circle& shape)
{
    return new CircleButton();
}

template<>
auto getNewButton(const Square& shape)
{
    return new SquareButton();
}


int main()
{
    Circle circle;
    Square square;

    std::vector<Button*> buttons;
    buttons.push_back(getNewButton(circle));
    buttons.push_back(getNewButton(square));

    for (auto pButton : buttons)
        pButton->click();

    return 0;
}
```